# AngularJS checkbox selected in a list

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a list called `positions` that has N positions in them. I also have a user `user` that has an attribute `user.positions` that has some of the positions assigned to.

I want to show a form with all the possible positions, and the positions that the user already has to be checked.

Is this something I can do inside the HTML, or do I need to loop through both in my logic and create a new variable?

Answer (score 2):

```
<label ng-repeat="position in positions">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="user.positions.indexOf(position) != -1" /> {{position}}
</label>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t4ZQd/

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked